# System of differential equations and Cauchy problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this system of differential equations:
$$z=y'$$
$$y=-z'-4$$

How would Cauchy's problem look for this equation, if I have z(0)=-4 and y(0)=1 ?

Comment: What exactly do you ask for; for the solution $(y(t), z(t))$? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $y$ and $z$ are each functions of $t$, we've got:

$(1) \ \ z(t)=y'(t)$

$(2)\ \  y(t)=-\color{green}{z'(t)}-4$.

Differentiate $(1)$ wrt. $t$, to give:

$(3) \ \ \color{green}{z'(t)=y''(t)}$.

Now, sub $(3)$ into $(2)$ to give:

$(4) \ \ y(t)=-\color{green}{y''(t)}-4$.

Re-arrange $(4)$  to give:

$(*)\ \ y''(t)+y(t)=4$

Now solve $(*)$ (it's an inhomogeneous second order ODE)!